# jQuery fast mouse move mouseleave event triggers before previous event completes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If a users mouse goes over a table cell then a dropdown box replaces the html with data loaded via a post call. This works fine if the users mouse move is not too quick, but if it is too fast the html doesn't update so that when the user moves the mouse back in the html is incorrect.

```
$(".edit_dropdown").bind('mouseenter', function () {
$(this).unbind('mouseenter');
var a = $.trim($(this).html());
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$(this).html("<span id='s-" + id + "'></span>");
$.post('save/dropdown.php', {
    id: id,
    a: a
}, function (data) {
    $("#s-" + id).html(data);

    $(".edit_dropdown").bind('mouseleave', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var a = $("#e-" + id).val();
        var dir = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).html(a);
        $(this).bind('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).unbind('mouseenter');
            var a = $.trim($(this).html());
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).html("<span id='s-" + id + "'></span>");
            $.post('save/dropdown.php', {
                id: id,
                a: a
            }, function (data) {
                $("#s-" + id).html(data);
            });
        });

    });
});
});
```

html

```
<tr>
<td>customer county</td>
<td class="edit_dropdown" id="customer-cust_s_county"><?php echo $row['cust_s_county']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

The $.post file returns a list of UK counties, if the county name matches the html then that county is returned as the selected option.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle so we could test the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the mouseleave handler is only put in place in response to an asynchronous response to the mouseenter handler.

You should be looking for a simpler overall code structure that doesn't involve detaching and reattaching handlers.

It should be possible to write two handlers that remain permanently attached, as follows :

```
$(".edit_dropdown").on('mouseenter', function () {
    //Perform all mouseenter actions here.
    //If necessary, test for different states and branch as required.
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    //Perform all mouseleave actions here.
    //If necessary, test for different states and branch as required.
});
```

Another point: As the list of counties is static, you can serve it once as part of the page's original HTML. You then need to return only the name or id of the county to be selected rather than repeatedly returning the whole list.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the .on makes the script a lot more simple, unfortunately if the mouse moves too quickly the mouseenter html change doesn't complete before the mouseleave. Is there away of delaying the mouseleave?

Comment: Aha, that's why I suggested that you consider testing for different states and branching as required. I expect you need to handle mouseleave differently if the mouseover's ajax has not yet responded. It's difficult for me to say for certain, as I don't fully understand what you atrying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what i am trying to achieve is on a table the user can view customer details, if they hover the mouse over the cell then the text becomes a text box or dropdown depending on the cells data, this works fine on a text box, the problem i have is when the edit needs to be a dropdown the text turns into a dropdown and the same value as the cell html is selected. What is happening the mouseenter call doesn't have time to get the selected item in the dropdown if the mouse passes too quickly hence not being able to pass it as the new html.

Comment: What I don't understand is (a) what happens on mouseleave and (b) what is supposed to happen on mouseleave.

Comment: Using the hoverIntent plugin i have done the equivalent of delaying the mouseleave call which allows time for the html to pass to the cell. I imagine this will depend on the internet connection speed as to how successful this will be with large amounts of post data. Thanks for your help